# A few questions about NSLocalNotifications

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate, uialertview, uilocalnotification

This is my localNotification codes.

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
        NSCalendar * calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];
        [calendar setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
        NSDateComponents* components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit | NSHourCalendarUnit | NSMinuteCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate];

        [components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];
        [components setHour:13];
        [components setMinute:11];
        [components setDay: sonOdemeGunuNumber.integerValue -3];

        NSDate *test = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];


        // Schedule the notification
        UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
        localNotification.fireDate = test;
        localNotification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ 3 days left.",_txtBankaAdi.text];
        localNotification.alertAction = @"Show item";
        localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone systemTimeZone];
        localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;
        localNotification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitDay;
        localNotification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitMonth;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];
```

sonOdemeGunuNumber is ToDoItem alert day(number of current day for example -3).

```
 if(sonOdemeGunuNumber.integerValue == currentDay.integerValue){
    localNotification.repeatInterval = nil; }
```

I wanted to notify user 3 days earlier and it should continue get alert until currentDay = sonOdemeGunuNumber.

1- If I write this if-else statement it will work ?

2- If user delete the localNotification Item in my TableView, in this case item is Bank Account  ? 
Bank Account localNotification will delete itself automatically ?

Thank you !
Have a nice day everyone...

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for if user delete the item in tableview i cancel deleted item's localNotification..

First of all, send ID with userInfo to the LocalNotification Center.

```
localNotification.userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_txtItemName.text,@"delThisNot", nil];
```

Secondly go and edit your tableView method.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

```
    UIApplication *app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    NSArray *eventArray = [app scheduledLocalNotifications];
    for (int i=0; i<[eventArray count]; i++)
    {
        UILocalNotification* oneEvent = [eventArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSDictionary *userInfoCurrent = oneEvent.userInfo;
        NSString *adi = [[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]valueForKey:@"odemeAdi"];
        NSString *uid=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[userInfoCurrent valueForKey:@"delThisNot"]];

        if ([uid isEqualToString:adi])
        {
            //Cancelling local notification
            [app cancelLocalNotification:oneEvent];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

adi = Deleting item.
uid = your item id (which is your txtItemName.text)

```
if ([uid isEqualToString:adi])
        {
            //Cancelling local notification
            [app cancelLocalNotification:oneEvent];
            break;
        }
```

if user want to delete item name (adi) == uid (txtItemName.Text)

Cancel this notification.

Sorry for my grammers I just wanted to help other people I hope you guys can understand me :D

Thanks.